# Pandas: Apply function to each group and store result in new column

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by, apply

I have an item dataframe such as:

```
item_df = pd.DataFrame({'BarCode': ['12345678AAAA', '12345678BBBB', '12345678CCCC',
                                    '12345678ABCD', '12345678EFGH', '12345678IJKL',
                                    '67890123XXXX', '67890123YYYY', '67890123ZZZZ',
                                    '67890123ABCD', '67890123EFGH', '67890123IJKL'],
                        'Extracted_Code': ['12345678','12345678', '12345678','12345678','12345678','12345678',
                                           '67890123','67890123', '67890123','67890123', '67890123','67890123'],
                        'Description': ['Fruits', 'Fruits', 'Fruits', 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Mangoes',
                                        'Snacks', 'Snacks', 'Snacks', 'Yoghurt', 'Cookies', 'Oats'],
                        'Category': ['H', 'H', 'H', 'M', 'T', 'S', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
                        'Code': ['0', '2', '3', '1', '2', '4', '0', '2', '3', '3', '4', '2'],
                        'Quantity': [99, 77, 10, 52, 11, 90, 99, 77, 10, 52, 11, 90],
                        'Price': [12.0, 10.5, 11.0, 15.6, 12.9, 67.0, 12.0, 10.5, 11.0, 15.6, 12.9, 67.0]})

item_df = item_df.sort_values(by=['Extracted_Code', 'Category', 'Code'])
item_df['Combined'] = np.NaN
```

What I am trying to achieve is a bit tricky. I have to perform groupby on `['Extracted_Code']` and for each group, create a new column `Combined`. The column `Combined` will have value based on:

1. For rows with Category='H', Combined will have NaN values.
2. For rows with Category other than 'H', suppose if we take a row with Category='M', then Combined column of that particular row will have a list of row jsons that has Category='H' in the same group and whose Code is less than or equal to Code of that particular row.

My desired result is:

```
  BarCode        Extracted_Code   Description   Category   Code    Quantity   Price    Combined
0 12345678AAAA   12345678         Fruits        H          0       99         12.0     NaN
1 12345678BBBB   12345678         Fruits        H          2       77         10.5     NaN
2 12345678CCCC   12345678         Fruits        H          3       10         11.0     NaN
3 12345678ABCD   12345678         Apples        M          1       52         15.6     [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0}]
4 12345678IJKL   12345678         Mangoes       S          4       90         67.0     [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '12345678BBBB', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '2', 'Quantity': 77, 'Price': 10.5},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '12345678CCCC', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '3', 'Quantity': 10, 'Price': 11.0}]
5 12345678EFGH   12345678         Oranges       T          2       11         12.9     [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '12345678BBBB', 'Description': 'Fruits', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '2', 'Quantity': 77, 'Price': 10.5}]
6 67890123IJKL   67890123         Oats          F          2       90         67.0     [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '67890123YYYY', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '2', 'Quantity': 77, 'Price': 10.5}]
7 67890123XXXX   67890123         Snacks        H          0       99         12.0     NaN
8 67890123YYYY   67890123         Snacks        H          2       77         10.5     NaN
9 67890123ZZZZ   67890123         Snacks        H          3       10         11.0     NaN
10 67890123ABCD  67890123         Yoghurt       M          3       52         15.6     [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '67890123YYYY', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '2', 'Quantity': 77, 'Price': 10.5},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '67890123ZZZZ', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '3', 'Quantity': 10, 'Price': 11.0}]
11 67890123EFGH  67890123         Cookies       M          4       11         12.9     [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '0', 'Quantity': 99, 'Price': 12.0},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '67890123YYYY', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '2', 'Quantity': 77, 'Price': 10.5},
                                                                                        {'BarCode': '67890123ZZZZ', 'Description': 'Snacks', 'Category': 'H', 'Code': '3', 'Quantity': 10, 'Price': 11.0}]
```

This is what I have done to get list of row jsons:

```
item_df.groupby(['Extracted_Code', 'Category', 'Code']).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(name='Combined')
```

But I am confused on how to apply the condition to each group without losing any columns in the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform a self-merge, and filter out rows that match your criteria:

```
m = df.reset_index().merge(df, on="Extracted_Code", suffixes=("_x", ""))
m = m[ (m["Category"] == "H") & (m["Code"] <= m["Code_x"]) & (m["Category_x"] != "H") ]
```

```
    index     BarCode_x Extracted_Code Description_x Category_x Code_x  Quantity_x  Price_x       BarCode Description Category Code  Quantity  Price
18      3  12345678ABCD       12345678        Apples          M      1          52     15.6  12345678AAAA      Fruits        H    0        99   12.0
24      5  12345678IJKL       12345678       Mangoes          S      4          90     67.0  12345678AAAA      Fruits        H    0        99   12.0
25      5  12345678IJKL       12345678       Mangoes          S      4          90     67.0  12345678BBBB      Fruits        H    2        77   10.5
26      5  12345678IJKL       12345678       Mangoes          S      4          90     67.0  12345678CCCC      Fruits        H    3        10   11.0
30      4  12345678EFGH       12345678       Oranges          T      2          11     12.9  12345678AAAA      Fruits        H    0        99   12.0
31      4  12345678EFGH       12345678       Oranges          T      2          11     12.9  12345678BBBB      Fruits        H    2        77   10.5
37     11  67890123IJKL       67890123          Oats          F      2          90     67.0  67890123XXXX      Snacks        H    0        99   12.0
38     11  67890123IJKL       67890123          Oats          F      2          90     67.0  67890123YYYY      Snacks        H    2        77   10.5
61      9  67890123ABCD       67890123       Yoghurt          M      3          52     15.6  67890123XXXX      Snacks        H    0        99   12.0
62      9  67890123ABCD       67890123       Yoghurt          M      3          52     15.6  67890123YYYY      Snacks        H    2        77   10.5
63      9  67890123ABCD       67890123       Yoghurt          M      3          52     15.6  67890123ZZZZ      Snacks        H    3        10   11.0
67     10  67890123EFGH       67890123       Cookies          M      4          11     12.9  67890123XXXX      Snacks        H    0        99   12.0
68     10  67890123EFGH       67890123       Cookies          M      4          11     12.9  67890123YYYY      Snacks        H    2        77   10.5
69     10  67890123EFGH       67890123       Cookies          M      4          11     12.9  67890123ZZZZ      Snacks        H    3        10   11.0
```

The `.reset_index()` allows you to then `.groupby("index")` which you could then add your `.to_dict("records")` to:

```
combined = m.groupby("index").apply(lambda group: 
   group[["BarCode", "Description", "Category", 
          "Code", "Quantity", "Price"
   ]].to_dict("records")
).rename("Combined")
```

Which you can then `.join`:

```
>>> df.join(combined)
         BarCode Extracted_Code Description Category Code  Quantity  Price                                           Combined
0   12345678AAAA       12345678      Fruits        H    0        99   12.0                                                NaN
1   12345678BBBB       12345678      Fruits        H    2        77   10.5                                                NaN
2   12345678CCCC       12345678      Fruits        H    3        10   11.0                                                NaN
3   12345678ABCD       12345678      Apples        M    1        52   15.6  [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'F...
5   12345678IJKL       12345678     Mangoes        S    4        90   67.0  [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'F...
4   12345678EFGH       12345678     Oranges        T    2        11   12.9  [{'BarCode': '12345678AAAA', 'Description': 'F...
11  67890123IJKL       67890123        Oats        F    2        90   67.0  [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'S...
6   67890123XXXX       67890123      Snacks        H    0        99   12.0                                                NaN
7   67890123YYYY       67890123      Snacks        H    2        77   10.5                                                NaN
8   67890123ZZZZ       67890123      Snacks        H    3        10   11.0                                                NaN
9   67890123ABCD       67890123     Yoghurt        M    3        52   15.6  [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'S...
10  67890123EFGH       67890123     Cookies        M    4        11   12.9  [{'BarCode': '67890123XXXX', 'Description': 'S...
```